# React installing local dependency tailwind missing

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have two react projects with this layout:

```
├── component-library
└── hello-world
```

The `hello-world` project is using components from the component-library and installs them like this:

```json
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "preinstall": "npm install ../component-library/",
    "link": "npm link ../component-library/node_modules/react && npm link ../component-library/node_modules/react-dom",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "component-library": "file:../component-library",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    ...
  },
}
```

This has worked like a charm, until I extended the `tailwind.config.js` with a new theme color.

```js
export default {
  content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
    colors: {
      orange: '#F26724',
      lightBlue: '#8ABFD9',
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

When I run the component-library with storybook everything looks as expected but the `hello-world` doesn't seem to import the CSS from the components.

Is there any setting I can do with tailwind in `hello-world` project to import CSS from the component-library?